# ODI Repository Migration

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

We are using ODI  12c version 12.1.2 in windows server 2012 with repository in Oracle 11g on a remote server , we are experiencing slow performance when using odi studio with repository being on s remote server we are trying to migrate our repository to be local on the same windows server , so we are asking about best practice to move the repository from database instance to another.

Answer (score 1):

I found on [this source](https://knowepmbi.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/odi-migration-move-repository-from-one-instance-to-another/) the steps to migrate the repository:

> The best way to relocate an ODI Repository from one RDBMS instance/server to another is to use the standard Import / Export tools delivered with database software and set the new connection parameters for the Repository.
>
> For example, the following procedure show how to relocate a Repository to a new Oracle instance:
>
> Physically copying the database schemas
>
> Use IMP/EXP or similar database tools, export the database and / or schemas containing the ODI Repositories and import them to the new database instance.
>
> Setting the new connection parameters with ODI
>
> 1. Launch Topology Manager. In the login window, edit the login parameter set and change the connection parameters to point to the new server which hosts the Master repository and logon to Topology Manager.
> 2. Expand the tree structure of the repositories.
> 3. Edit each Work Repository that is now hosted on a new server and edit its connection parameters by clicking on the Connection button
> 4. Modify the connection parameters (URL and user) of the Work Repository and save it by clicking ‘OK’
> 5. Launch Designer. In the Login Window, edit the login properties and change the connection to the Master Repository to comply with the new server properties.
> 6. Modify your odiparams.bat (.sh) script to reflect the new connection parameters to your Master Repository.
> 7. For each ODI Agent configuration do not forget to update the odiparams.bat (.sh) script as indicated in step 6 above.